# The additive group $(\Bbb Z[X], +)$ is not isomorphic to the additive group of rationals $(\mathbb{Q},+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to show that

> $(\Bbb Z[X], +)$ is not isomorphic to the additive group of rationals $(\mathbb{Q},+)$.

I basically want to know if my method is correct.

**My steps**

Let $\phi : (\Bbb Z[X], +) \to (\mathbb{Q},+)$ be an isomorphism then if $\phi(1)=c$, and $\phi(x)=r$ .
Then we have $\phi(a_0 + a_1 x +\cdots + a_nx^n) = a_0 \phi(1)+ a_1\phi(1)\phi(x)+a_2 \phi(1)\phi(x)^2 + \cdots + a_n \phi(1) \phi(x)^n$

So we can see that $\mathbb{Q}$ is being generated by linear combination of $\phi(1)=c$ and $\phi(x)=r$, $i.e.$ $\mathbb{Q}$ is finitely generated, a contradiction to the fact that $\Bbb Q$ is not finitely generated by rationals.

So is my proof correct?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a multiplication in your $\mathbb{Q}(+)$? i.e, did you mean the ring $(\mathbb{Q}, + , \cdot)?$

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb Q$ is a [divisible group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group)

Comment: The question is already ill-defined. There cannot be an isomorphism between a ring and a group.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes, I have corrected the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, no, it's not correct. You're assuming that $\phi$ is a *ring* isomorphism, but you can't do it. And, in any case, you have not proved your claim, because you have proved that $\mathbb{Q}$ is generated as a group by the elements $cr^n$, not by $c$ and $r$.

Hint: is there an element $f(X)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $2f(X)=1$?

Comment: So the hint you provided basically uses that 2 is not a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ but I am unable to follow how exactly may I come to the point $2f(x)=1$?

Comment: @Kashif If $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}[X]\to\mathbb{Q}$ is a group homomorphism, then $\varphi(1)=r\ne0$ and there exists $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\varphi(f)=r/2$. But then $\varphi(2f)=\varphi(1)$, implying $2f(x)=1$. No ring unit involved.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is not correct because you can't claim that $\phi(X^n) =\phi(X)^n$.

*Hint:* There is no injective additive function $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Q}$.

> Indeed, if $\phi(1)=a/b$ and $\phi(X)=c/d$, then $\phi(bc)=\phi(adX)$.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to find an equation that is solvable in one but not solvable in the other.

For example, in $\mathbb Q$ you can half anything, so given $n$ you can always solve $n = x + x$.

This can't always be solved in $\mathbb Z[X]$ so the rings are not isomorphic.